# Automatically set a batch of pages to go live

Tags: product-page, automation

Is there a built in method, 3rd party add on, or macro that could help us put mages live without manually doing so? My goal is to set pages live at midnight but sometimes that's not possible so things get postponed.

Answer (score 2):

Im not aware of any custom extension that will provide this functionality. I may be wrong as I have not googled to see what is available.

However depending on your level of ability in code the process is not that complicated. If all you want to do is mark pages from draft to live then a simple cron job will do the trick:

Process being: 
   * Load all cms pages where status != live `Mage::getModel('cms/page');`
   * Iterate over all setting published status to live and save the page

This can run at midnight and will push pages live for you. Perhaps cache might need to be purged at the end.

The negative to this is it is very simple, So there is no middle ground. All posts will be pushed live at midnight. Alternative being that you would need to look at a different workflow for pushing and publishing content to live. Perhaps custom post status codes or a new attribute that can hold state: Draft, Pending Approval, Approved, Live